# square root of infinite number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, roots

I am not even sure how to call this or what tags to use, but here it goes. Is

$$\sqrt{\underbrace{1....1}_{2n\text{ digits}} -\underbrace{2....2}_{n\text{ digits}}}=\underbrace{3.....3}_{n\text{ digits}}$$

where $1...1$ has $2n$ figures, and $2...2$ and $3...3$ have $n$ figures each.

I dont even know how to start proving this. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Let $x = 11\ldots1$  with $n$ ones.   Then your equation is $\sqrt{10^n x + x -2x} = 3x.$

Comment: This helped so much, it seems so easy now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^{2n}10^{i}-2\sum_{i=0}^{n}10^{i}}=\sqrt{10^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}10^{i}-\sum_{i=0}^{n}10^{i}}=\sqrt{\left ( 10^{n}-1 \right )\sum_{i=0}^{n}10^{i}}$$

Now we go back to decimal notation, recognizing $10^{n}-1=\underset{\text{n times}}{9\dots9}=9(\underset{\text{n times}}{1\dots1})$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{n}10^{i}=\underset{\text{n times}}{1\dots1}$ gives the result.